# Word + yet + word

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

Is it correct to say

> It's compact, yet concise to let us know about the important notes.

Also, could enough be used after "concise"?

> It's compact, yet concise enough to let us know about the important notes.

How would you reword this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use "word1 + yet + word2," the second word is usually a contradiction to the first word in some way. What you are saying is that *even though* it's word1, it still has some qualities of word2 (which you wouldn't have originally assumed, since usually things have either quality but not both). In this case, compact and concise mean almost the same thing, so the "yet" doesn't really make sense here.

For example, in the sentence "It's concise, yet informative enough to let us know about the important notes," "concise" and "informative" are in some way contradictory, because "concise" means it's written in short, and "informative" means it contains valuable information. So when we say that something has both of these qualities, we mean that *even though* it's concise, it is still informative.

Depending on the situation, you may or may not need "enough". If you want to emphasize that the first adjective is "mainly true" and the second one is only "a little bit true" or only true in certain cases, you might use "enough". However, you can say an article is "concise yet informative" (without qualifying the "informative") and that is correct as well.

Comment: You're right! I thought "compact" meant something that is summarized to a short writing (In case of writings and not other apparatus) and "concise" meant short but containing all the necessary information. Now I see that "compact" is the same word in some ways. Thank you for the quick answer!